# Why Am I Able to Use user() method in laravel, without even defining it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I do have a `UserController` and `User` Model in my Laravel 5 source.
Also there is one `AuthController` is also Present (shipped prebuilt with laravel source).

I would like to query data from db in my blades making use of Eloquent Models.

However, Neither in my `User` Model (Eloquent ) nor in any of the controller, the `user()` method is defined. even then, I could use it in my blade by accessing it from `Auth` class. why?

For example,

in my blade, `{{ Auth::user()->fname }}` works. it retrieve the data `fname`from my `users` table and echo it.

What is the logic behind it, and can i emulate the same for other db tables such as `tasks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do it automatically or manually some like this

```
 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) 
{
}
```

The selected User's Data will be stored in the `storage/framework/sessions`

It will have data something like

```
a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"PEKGoLhoXMl1rUDNNq2besE1iSTtSKylFFIhuoZu";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:43:"http://localhost/Learnings/laravel5/laravel";}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1432617607;s:1:"c";i:1432617607;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}
```

The above sessions file doesn't have any data and it will have the data such as user's id, url, token  in json format.

Then whenever you call the `{{ Auth::user()->fname }}` Laravel recognises that you're trying to fetch the logged in user's `fname` then laravel will fetch the file and get the user's primary key and refer it from the user's table from your database. and you can do it for all coloumns of the users `table` that you have.

You can learn more about it [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: That is pretty awesome. However, if i would like to query other tables I'll have to use the custom Eloquent models for the same table , and Auth class will not help in that case , am i right ?

Comment: Yes it is.. Your questions makes me to write a post in my own website.. Soon i will write the goodness of `Auth` as a post in my personal website :)

Comment: But if you want to achieve with inside model, You can go it by passing param to the model's function by calling it from the Controller .. +1 for making me to think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

This user function is defined under

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php
```

with following content :

```
/**
 * Get the currently authenticated user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function user()
{
    if ($this->loggedOut) return;

    // If we have already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
    // return it back immediately. We do not want to pull the user data every
    // request into the method because that would tremendously slow an app.
    if ( ! is_null($this->user))
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    $id = $this->session->get($this->getName());

    // First we will try to load the user using the identifier in the session if
    // one exists. Otherwise we will check for a "remember me" cookie in this
    // request, and if one exists, attempt to retrieve the user using that.
    $user = null;

    if ( ! is_null($id))
    {
        $user = $this->provider->retrieveById($id);
    }

    // If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
    // pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
    // the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
    $recaller = $this->getRecaller();

    if (is_null($user) && ! is_null($recaller))
    {
        $user = $this->getUserByRecaller($recaller);

        if ($user)
        {
            $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());

            $this->fireLoginEvent($user, true);
        }
    }

    return $this->user = $user;
}
```

this Guard.php has more functions defined in it which we use every now and then without even knowing where they are coming from

Comment: That's my real name. I even has website with my name. :P

Comment: just checked nice. 
I also need to server different views to different user types, and wondering if i can implement any kind of filter while defining `$this->middleware('auth');` in my HomeController ?  like using my `user()->type==admin` entry from `users` table? 
or should i create a separate question  thread for this?

Comment: You should not post questions about everything. First do some R&D and if you are not getting answer then only post a question. My contact details are available on my website if you have any questions I will be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

It works because Laravel comes with decent authentication.

Auth is the authentication library and has plenty of features like this, check out the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)!